# What are the compilers available that target JVM or CLR apart from javac or Microsoft's compilers for .Net?

Tags: java, .net, compiler-construction, jvm, clr

What are the compilers available that target JVM or CLR apart from javac or Microsoft's compilers for .Net? Why don't we have compilers for popular languages like C, C++ that target JVM or CLR?

Comment: Actually there have been attempts to compile C to the JVM, but I doubt they fared well. Manual memory management and pointer arithmetic just don't fit the JVM, and even then it's a lot of work for pretty much zero gain. What would you expect from a C compiler emitting JVM bytecode?

Comment: Do you really mean only compiler or are you fine with all the interpreters that exist for the JVM too? There'd be at least JRuby and JPython. I think Clojure and Scala both compile down to bytecode and not java too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wikipedia has good information on this:

- [List of JVM languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_JVM_languages)
- [List of CLI languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_CLI_languages)

> Why don't we have compilers for popular languages like C, C++ that target JVM or CLR?

Well, there's C++/CLI. Links:

- [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++/CLI)
- [ECMA spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-372.htm)
- [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xey702bw.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

When it comes to .NET there is [mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page).

The [fsf](http://www.fsf.org/) has a [Java compiler](http://gcc.gnu.org/java/) as part of the [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org).

As for why there are no exiting compilers that compiler from C/C++ to the JVM/CLR - not sure this is the case, but apart from the massively different memory models, you need to recall that these languages are also partially specified by the accompanying libraries (say libc) - these are not small and also need to be converted, not a small feat either.

Answer (score 1):

Plenty of compilers exist that compiles to byte code, especially in the Java world, where the byte code level is on a very high level, so it is relatively easy to write a compiler for it.

For C the problem is that the abstraction of the machine needed by the compiled program is on a *lower* level than provided by the JVM.  E.g. for pointer arithmetic to work you must have a single, large chunk of memory where everything is placed which is against the Java view of the world as a lot of independent objects.

It can be done, however. [NestedVM](http://nestedvm.ibex.org/) solves this by compiling C programs to a MIPS-CPU with a custom runtime library.  The generated code is then interpreted directly or as byte codes.

Answer (score 0):

RemObjects has Oxygene compilers for JVM and .NET (aka Pascal for Java and .NET).

http://www.remobjects.com/oxygene/

Microsoft does have VC++ compiler for CLR, but that is an extension to C++ (C++/CLR). Due to this fact, nobody tries to tailor C++ for JVM (as far as I know).

C is not an OO language, so unless heavily tailored (like C++/CLR), it is not suitable for JVM nor CLR.